# Gazebo Plugin not found

Tags: simulation, gazebo

I am trying to simulate wind on gazebo garden on ubuntu 22.04. So, I found this plugin `libgz-sim-wind-effects-system.so` in my plugins path and included it as follows:

```
<plugin name="gz::sim::v7::systems::WindEffects" filename="libgz-sim-wind-effects-system.so">
                <direction>0</direction>
                <speed>100000</speed>
                <turbulence>0.5</turbulence>
            </plugin>
```

However, I keep getting this error

```
`Failed to load plugin [libgz-sim-wind-effects-system.so] : couldn't find shared library.`
```

But the file exists in the same path as other plugins I'm using in the same file and I added the path of the file to the environment variable as such

```
export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

So, any idea what is the problem here? Also, is this the correct plugin and should I be another plugin to simulate wind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```xml
    <plugin
      filename="gz-sim-wind-effects-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::WindEffects">
```

So you'd need to remove `lib` from the `filename`. Also, it's not necessary to include the anonymous namespace `v7`.

You can also run the `wind.sdf` example and see if that works for you:
https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/af73ebe7c8c693fd54e391f79c11bf9f24df2640/examples/worlds/wind.sdf

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks a lot!